# React Native: How to show screen state variable updates in HeaderRight custom component using Context Api

Tags: react-native, state, stack-navigator, react-context

I'm new to React Native and I want to pass state variable **cartTotal** from **Cart** **component** to the **custom HeaderRight** **CartCounter** **component** so that when I update cartTotal variable in Cart component changes are visible in CartCounter component where I show it. I don't wanna use Redux, but I know that is possible with **Context Api**. I did a long search to find an example similar to mine but I didn't find it. Can you show me how to use it in my case?

Here my code

**Cart Component**

export default class Cart extends React.Component {

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    

    return {            
        headerTransparent: true,
        headerTintColor: "black",
        headerRight: () => {
            return <CartCounter cartTotal={this.state.cartTotal} />
        }
    };
}

constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {                          
        cartTotal: 0
    }
}
...
...
...
```

**CartCounter Component**

```
export default class CartCounter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render() {
        return (        

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.onPress }>
                    <View style={ styles.root }>
                        <Text style={ styles.total }>{ cart total updates I want to see } </Text>      
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity> 
            
        )
    }
}
...
...
...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use react context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html to create a global state and seter